# @JsonDeserialize causing HTTP 415

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a Spring Boot application and I've written a custom Deserializer for one of my Entities. I've added `@JsonDeserialize(using = GuestOrderDeserializer.class)` to the Entity and now, anytime I try and access any of my endpoints that have to deserialize data, even when it has nothing to do with `GuestOrder`, I get a http status returned of 415.

However, if I add the deserializer like this:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(GuestOrder.class, new GuestOrderDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

Then it works just fine. That said, this is causing issues elsewhere, so I'd like to just use `@JsonDeserializer` on the appropriate entities. I just don't know why it is causing a `415`.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know the nitty gritty details of why, but basically since I'm doing custom deserialization, I had several collection properties annotated with `@JsonManagedRefernece` and removing those resolve the issue. The error message implied that I wasn't dealing with those in my custom deserializers which I find odd. But TL;DR removing those solved the problem and no side effects because I kept the `@JsonBackReference` in the child entities.